# show a function is riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Define $\phi(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $0<x\leq 1 $ and $\phi(0)=0$. If $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, show that $f \circ \phi$ is also Riemann integrable.

Denote $D(f)$ to be the set of discontinuities of $f$.

Since $D(f \circ \phi) \subset D(f) \cup D(\phi)=D(f) \cup \{0\}$ and by Riemann Lebesgue theorem, we have $D(f)$ is a zero set. Since subset of zero set is again zero set, by Riemann Lebesgue theorem, $f \circ \phi$ is Riemann integrable.

Question: Is $D(f \circ \phi) \subset D(f) \cup D(\phi)$ correct in this question?

EDIT: Is $\phi(D(f \circ \phi)) = D(f)$ true here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $D(f\circ\phi)\subset D(f)\cup D(\phi)$ does not hold. See, for example, $\phi(x)=x+1$ on $[0,1]$ and $f$ a function which is discontinuous at $1.5$., for example,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x\in[1,1.5)\\1&\text{if }x\in[1.5,2)\end{cases}$$

In that case, you have $$(f\circ \phi)(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x\in[0,0.5)\\1&\text{if }x\in[0.5,1)\end{cases}$$

so $D(f\circ\phi) = \{0.5\}\not\subset\{1.5\} = D(f)\cup D(\phi).$

Comment: does it hold if i define $\phi$ as in the question above?

Comment: No. If $f$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$, for example, the $f\circ \phi$ has discontinuity for all values $x$ for which $\phi(x) = x_0$. This set does not need to (and, in general, does not) include $x_0$.